# How to save the option selected in UIPickerView and Load it back up

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcodebuild

i just made a UIPickerView showing all of the countries. but when i leave the page and go back its back at the top. is there a easy way like NSUserdefaults to save the option?

Answer (score 0):

You could call inside viewWillDisappear of your UIViewController to get the current country

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Then convert the NSInteger to a NSNumber and save it with NSUserDefaults.

And when it's coming back to the view in the view controller's viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad (depending on your project) you could retrieve the NSInteger from the defaults and use it to call

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Set the animated BOOL to NO if you don't want an animation every time you enter in that view.

Hope this helps